# Как отправлять сообщение первым от телеграм бота? Python Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Я замечал такое, что телеграм боты порой сами пишут человеку в личку. Не в смысле из неоткуда, а например если человек и бот в одной группе находятся. Я искал информацию по этому поводу, но ничего не смог найти. Как это реализуется?

Comment: Исходя из описания API телеграмма, то бот не может первым писать, а только отвечать на сообщения.

Comment: Да, но я видел, что бот писал первым пользователю, при этом пользователь никогда не отправлял боту команду /start. Как именно это можно было реализовать?

Comment: да, мне тоже так постоянно пишут боты (ниоткуда)
и ещё мне пишут сразу боты когда я поступаю в приватный канал к которуму заявку кинуть надо

Comment: Вот тут немного о приватности для ботов https://core.telegram.org/bots/features#privacy-mode полагаю, что бот может отслеживать заявки на вступление в каналы, уведомления о вступлении в чат и неявные сообщения в рамках группы в которую он добавлен, но не более. Как именно это реализуется из описания API не сильно понятно...

Answer (score 0):

Для этого нужно создать ссылку на канал с подтверждением входа от админа
[image: Request admin approval]

При переходе по такой ссылке юзер будет не подписываться на канал, а подавать заявку. Если в канал добавлен бот, то он может подтверждать заявку (например, [метод в aiogram](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/types/chat_join_request.html#aiogram.types.chat_join_request.ChatJoinRequest.approve)), и у него появляется возможность писать пользователю по праву администрирования.